# AnimAll: Why when I press insert key in the animation workspace, my timeline don't show any keyframe

Tags: animation, keyframes, animation-nodes

My **blender version** is **4.0.1**, I had also try before **blender 3.6** but both of them also **not shown the keyframe at timeline**. I had tried press **I** and **scroll up** the timeline  but **still can't see the keyframe**[image].

I'm watching the **tutorial from YouTube**,you may **check it out**
[from here](https://youtu.be/wht7VOQRyM8?t=26m59s).

Comment: Hello, TT, AnimAll needs you to press 'Insert key' in its own panel, on the right. '**I**' doesn't work. Is that it?